# Jquery Cycle plugin with maphilight stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2, maphilight

I am using jquery cycle plugin with jquery maphilight to highlight products on the flyer that is causing some problem as you can see in first screenshot how it works but when i add maphilight then check screenshot 2 this is how it shows. 
you can check it on jsFiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/Yjuqs/

This is the code for jquery cycle plugin and jquery maphilight

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
<script>$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';</script>
$(function() {
        $('img').maphilight({
            fade:true,
            fadeDuration:500 ,
            fillOpacity :0.2,
            stroke:false,
            fillColor:'ffffff'

        });
    });
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Please use document ready jQuery function, call function when the document ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow'; //call slider
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yes already tried this if i add document ready then next previous button also stop working and images show one after other, without document ready everything is working only images overlap each other.

Comment: I found the issue is not with jquery but with jquery maphilight plugin if i add it then this happens otherwise it works fine you can check here

http://jsfiddle.net/Yjuqs/